# Android Google Map (SupportMapFragment) Not Displaying Points

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2, supportmapfragment

Using the SupportMapFragment I'm able to get a map to display and load into the view. However that's all it's doing. I can't get it to load points, zoom, or anything that has any value.

**What is wrong here?**

I am using the following Fragment to spin up a SupportMapFragment.

```
public class MapLocationFragment extends Fragment {

    public static MapLocationFragment getInstance()
    {
        return new MapLocationFragment();
    }

    static final LatLng HAMBURG = new LatLng(53.558, 9.927);
    static final LatLng KIEL = new LatLng(53.551, 9.993);
    private GoogleMap map;

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.view_map_location_fragment, null, false);

        map = ((SupportMapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
                .getMap();

        Marker hamburg = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(HAMBURG)
                .title("Hamburg"));
        Marker kiel = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .position(KIEL)
                .title("Kiel")
                .snippet("Kiel is cool")
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                        .fromResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher)));

        map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(HAMBURG, 15));
        map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(10), 2000, null);

        return v;
    }
}
```

My Activity looks like the following:

```
public class MapLocationActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.view_map_location);

        // handle beer venue list
        MapLocationFragment fragment = MapLocationFragment.getInstance();

        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.venueMapSection, fragment)
                .commit();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to override `onMapReady(GoogleMap map)` method. See [onMapReady](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/OnMapReadyCallback.html#onMapReady(com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap)).